# How to update a matrix of probabilities

Tags: python, algorithm, probability, bayesian

I am trying to find/figure out a function that can update probabilities.

Suppose there are three players and each of them get a fruit out of a basket: `["apple", "orange", "banana"]`

I store the probabilities of each player having each fruit in a matrix (like this table):

|  | apple | orange | banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Player 1** | 0.3333 | 0.3333 | 0.3333 |
| **Player 2** | 0.3333 | 0.3333 | 0.3333 |
| **Player 3** | 0.3333 | 0.3333 | 0.3333 |

The table can be interpreted as the belief of someone (*S*) who doesn't know who has what. Each row and column sums to 1.0 because each player has one of the fruits and each fruit is at one of the players.

I want to update these probabilities based on some knowledge that *S* gains. Example information:

**Player 1** did X. We know that **Player 1** does X with 80% probability if he has an **apple**. With 50% if he has an **orange**. With 10% if he has a **banana**.

This can be written more concisely as `[0.8, 0.5, 0.1]` and let us call it `reach_probability`.

---

A fairly easy to comprehend example is:

```
probabilities = [
    [0.5, 0.5, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.5, 0.5],
    [0.5, 0.0, 0.5],
]

# Player 1's 
reach_probability = [1.0, 0.0, 1.0]

new_probabilities = [
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
]
```

The above example can be fairly easily thought through.

---

another example:

```
probabilities = [
    [0.25, 0.25, 0.50],
    [0.25, 0.50, 0.25],
    [0.50, 0.25, 0.25],
]

# Player 1's 
reach_probability = [1.0, 0.5, 0.5]

new_probabilities = [
    [0.4, 0.2, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.3, 0.3],
]
```

---

In my use case using a simulation is not an option. My probabilities matrix is big. Not sure if the only way to calculate this is using an iterative algorithm or if there is a better way.

I looked at bayesian stuff and not sure how to apply it in this case. Updating it row by row then spreading out the difference proportionally to the previous probabilities seems promising but I haven't managed to make it work correctly. Maybe it isn't even possible like that.

Comment: This is a really interesting problem. I have worked with evidence of the form "it is not X" in the context of Bayesian belief networks. "It is not X" evidence is represented as a likelihood function which is zero for X and 1 for anything else. The effect is just as you describe, that some elements in the probability matrix get clobbered with zero. Looking at your program, I don't know how to fix it, but you should be able to work out the right calculation if you think about computing the posterior P(not X | it is not X) from P(X, not X) (i.e., what you started with) and the likelihood.

Comment: Keeping that stuff straight isn't easy, although once you get it sorted out the computations are simple. My advice is take a look at Bayesian inference and belief networks. That's going to be vast overkill but then you'll be able to work out the simple calculation that's needed here.

Comment: I wrote a simulation so I could check algorithms against it. The way I intuitively calculated it is often wrong. Looking at bayesian belief networks wasn't very helpful yet. I'll keep looking... Simulation is not an option for my use case as I have a much bigger probability matrix. And it has to be accurate.

Comment: "My probabilities matrix is big (1326, 7)" Wait, is it not square? I thought I understood the problem, but that would rule out a 1-1 matching.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I understand how that might be misleading so I removed it. That is how I store it because you might imagine that one of the rows is not a player but the rest of the players. If I can work it out for a simple square that is good enough.

Comment: I don't understand the first example. `[1 0 1]` reach proba. So player 1 can have two fruits. However, the first row of the new matrix is `[1 0 0]`

Comment: @Damien Imagine we can ask **Player 1** what he would do with each fruit. The first number is with what percentage he would do X when he has an **apple**, second is with **orange**... `[1, 1, 1]` would mean for example that regardless of what fruit **Player 1** has he would do X 100% of the time.

Comment: What I don't understand is the result, I.e. the 1st row of the matrix

Comment: Which is the name of this problem?

Comment: Player 1 did X. We know that Player 1 does X with 80% probability if he has an apple. With 50% if he has an orange. With 10% if he has a banana.

This can be written more concisely as [0.8, 0.5, 0.1] and let us call it reach_probability.

Comment: However in the examples reach_probability. =[0.8, 0.5, 0.1]

Comment: I suspect this something used in Game Theory.

Comment: @RafaelValero yes it can be framed in terms of game theory as nodes in a game tree and we got to a new node by the action X.

Answer (score 4):

Initial condition: p(apple) = p(orange) = p(banana) = 1/3.

Player 1 did X. We know that Player 1 does X with 80% probability if he has an apple. With 50% if he has an orange. With 10% if he has a banana.

p(X | apple) = 0.8
p(x | orange) = 0.5
p(x | banana) = 0.1

Since apple, orange, and banana are all equally likely at 1/3, we have p(x) = 1/3 * 1.4)  ~ 0.466666666.

Recall Bayes theorem: p(a | b) = p(b|a) * p(a) / p(b)

So p(apple | x) = p(x | apple) * p(apple) / p(x) = 0.8 * (1/3) / 0.46666666 ~ 57.14%

similarly p(orange | x) = 0.5 * (1/3) / 0.46666666 ~ 35.71%

and p(banana | x) = 0.1 * (1/3) / 0.46666666 ~ 7.14%

Taking your example:

```
probabilities = [
    [0.25, 0.25, 0.50],
    [0.25, 0.50, 0.25],
    [0.50, 0.25, 0.25],
]

# Player 1's 
reach_probability = [1.0, 0.5, 0.5]

new_probabilities = [
    [0.4, 0.2, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.3, 0.3],
]

p(x) = 0.25 * 1.0 + 0.25 * 0.5 + 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.625
p(a|x) = p(x|a) * p(a) / p(x) = 1.0 * 0.25 / 0.625 = 0.4
p(b|x) = p(x|b) * p(b) / p(x) = 0.5 * 0.25 / 0.625 = 0.2
p(c|x) = p(x|c) * p(c) / p(x) = 0.5 * 0.50 / 0.625 = 0.4
```

As desired. The other entries of each column can just be scaled to get a column sum of 1.0.

E.g. in column 1 we multiple the other entries by (1-0.4)/(1-0.25). This takes 0.25 -> 0.2 and 0.50 -> 0.40. Similarly for the other columns.

```
new_probabilities = [
    [0.4, 0.200, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.533, 0.3],
    [0.4, 0.266, 0.3],
]
```

If then player 2 does y with the same conditional probabilities we get:

```
p(y) = 0.2 * 1.0 + 0.533 * 0.5 + 0.3 * 0.5 = 0.6165
p(a|y) = p(y|a) * p(a) / p(y) = 1.0 * 0.2 / 0.6165 = 0.3244
p(b|y) = p(y|b) * p(b) / p(y) = 0.5 * 0.533 / 0.6165 = 0.4323
p(c|y) = p(y|c) * p(c) / p(y) = 0.5 * 0.266 / 0.6165 = 0.2157
```

Comment: There we go this looks very good. I'll see how practical this is in my solution but this is definitely the answer to the question I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check this document:
[Endgame Solving in Large Imperfect-Information Games∗](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.698.5417&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

(S. Ganzfried, T. Sandholm, in International Conference on Autonomous Agents and MultiAgent Systems (AAMAS) (2015), pp. 37–45.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this - have not worked through whether this has problems too but it seems alright in your examples.

Assume each update is of the form "X,Y has probability p'" Mark element X,Y dirty with delta p - p', where p was the old probability. Now, redistribute the delta proportionally to all unmarked elements in the row, then the column, marking each dirty with its own delta, and marking the first clean. Continue until no dirty entry remains.

```
0.5   0.5   0.0
0.0   0.5   0.5
0.5   0.0   0.5

Belief: 2,1 has probability zero.

0.5   0.0*  0.0    update 2,1 and mark dirty
0.0   0.5   0.5    delta is 0.5
0.5   0.0   0.5

1.0*  0.0'  0.0    distribute 0.5 to row & col
0.0   1.0*  0.5    update as dirty, both deltas -0.5
0.5   0.0   0.5

1.0'  0.0'  0.0    distribute -0.5 to rows & cols
0.0   1.0'  0.0*   update as dirty, both deltas 0.5
0.0*  0.0   0.5

1.0'  0.0'  0.0    distribute 0.5 to row & col
0.0   1.0'  0.0'   update as dirty, delta is -0.5
0.0'  0.0   1.0*

1.0'  0.0'  0.0    distribute on row/col
0.0   1.0'  0.0'   no new dirty elements, complete
0.0'  0.0   1.0'
```

In your first example:

```
1/3   1/3   1/3
1/3   1/3   1/3
1/3   1/3   1/3

Belief: 3,1 has probability 0

1/3   1/3   0*     update 3,1 to zero, mark dirty
1/3   1/3   1/3   delta is 1/3
1/3   1/3   1/3

1/2*  1/2*  0'    distribute 1/3 proportionally across row then col
1/3   1/3   1/2*  delta is -1/6
1/3   1/3   1/2*

1/2'  1/2'  0'    distribute -1/6 proportionally across row then col
1/4*  1/4*  1/2'  delta is 1/12
1/4*  1/4*  1/2'

1/2'  1/2'  0'    distribute prportionally to unmarked entries
1/4'  1/4'  1/2' no new dirty entries, terminate
1/4'  1/4'  1/2'
```

You can mark entries dirty by inserting them with associated deltas into a queue and a hashset. Entries in both the queue and hash set are dirty. Entries in the hashset only are clean. Process the queue until you run out of entries.

I do not show an example where distribution is uneven, but the key is to distribute proportionally. Entries with 0 can never become non-zero except by a new belief.

Comment: I think this would indeed be correct if I could start with knowledge in the form of "X,Y has probability p". I don't think I have this. I am going to update my question to be clearer then think through your answer more. It seems promising. Thanks.

Comment: I thought at first that the first row can be calculated by just multiplying together the reach probabilities and the first row. Then re-normalizing it. Then we could have info in the form of "X,Y has probability p". But as the harder example shows doing that is incorrect.

Comment: answering your comment about decomposing the updates: I don't think there is a way to break up the update.

Comment: @Hadus I see your update appears to be multiplying along a row... so in a sense, you have an opportunity to update each of the non-zero entries to any other valid value. Your update can first be scaled so that the result keeps the row with sum 1. Then, we need to find an equivalent sequence of single-change updates which give the same result. This may not be simple. I can work out the case n=3 by hand but it is ugly. I wonder if you couldn't just set the whole row and mark the whole row dirty together.

Comment: What I am saying is that multiplying along the first row doesn't even give the correct ratio  but I am not sure if it becomes correct if we keep following the dirty around. I am going to try your answer with "first be scaled so that the result keeps the row with sum 1." and see what happens :)

Comment: I don't think this kind of working out is compatible with a whole row update from what I tried.

Comment: @Hadus Probably not. Though, I wonder how your simulation result is compatible with your update. It seems that the first and second entries are about in the same ratio your update suggests, but the third one is off. Maybe the issue is that in the general case you can't just go through once... you might have to keep going around and around until the deltas all fall under some threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there’s no known nice solution.

The way that I would apply Bayesian reasoning is to store a likelihood
matrix instead of a probability matrix. (Actually I’d store
log-likelihoods to prevent underflow, but that’s an implementation
detail.) We can start with the matrix

|  | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **2** | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **3** | 1 | 1 | 1 |

representing no knowledge. You could use the all-1/3 matrix instead, but
I’ve used 1 to emphasize that normalization is not required. To apply an
update like Player 1 doing X with conditional probabilities [0.8, 0.5,
0.1], we just multiply the row element-wise:

|  | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0.8 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| **2** | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **3** | 1 | 1 | 1 |

If Player 1 does Y independently with the same conditional
probabilities, then we get

|  | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 0.64 | 0.25 | 0.01 |
| **2** | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| **3** | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Now, the rub is that these likelihoods don’t have a nice relationship to
probabilities of specific outcomes. All we know is that the probability
of a specific matching is proportional to the product of its matrix
entries. As a simple example, with a matrix like

|  | Apple | Orange | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| **2** | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| **3** | 0 | 1 | 1 |

the entry for Player 3 having Orange is 1, yet this assignment has
probability 0 because both possibilities for completing the matching
have probability 0.

What we need is the
[permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_(mathematics)),
which sums the likelihood of every matching, and the minor for each
matrix entry, which sums the likelihood of every matching that makes the
corresponding assignment. Unfortunately we don’t know a good exact
algorithm for computing the permanent, and experts are skeptical that
one exists (the problem is NP-hard, and actually #P-complete). The
known approximation employs sampling via Markov chains.

Comment: I was thinking this might be NP-hard. I actually need this matrix for sampling possible "worlds" after there were some of these updates. Could we sample from likelihoods easily? So far this looks like the best answer Thanks :)

Comment: @Hadus there's a rapidly mixing Markov chain, so if approximate is OK, you're in luck. I'll post more when I get a chance.

Comment: Yes approximation is ok if there is no better way. Looking at permanent is pretty high level maths for me so if there are python libraries (or any) that do this that would be amazing.

Comment: @Hadus Hmm, so my memory was off. "Rapidly mixing" is polynomial but the exponent is 7 (!). Meanwhile Ryser's formula will give an exact evaluation but takes time O(n 2^n). I don't think either of these are practical for matrices with dimension >1,000.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Thank you for looking into it. If you can update your answer to include that I think it will be good enough to get the bounty unless someone else will find some way to make it work.